# Stop Lilypond from generating multiple files

Tags: windows-10, lilypond

Every time I compile a .ly file using lilypond for Windows10 it generates too many files. It outputs a pdf for the whole piece (which is what I need), and a separate pdf for each line of the piece + a .eps file for each one of those pdfs + some additional log files.

I have tried compiling both using cmd and double clicking on the .ly file. On command line, I have tried adding --pdf, --loglevel=NONE, --output=FILE, -fpdf but nothing seems to help

lilypond -fpdf --loglevel=NONE --output=pathToPDF pathToLyFile

Comment: Maybe you can use the flag `-dno-print-pages`

Comment: Just tried both '-dno-print-pages' and '-dprint-pages', but it still produces all the clutter